# "JSF - HTTP Status 404 – Não Encontrado" o que pode ser, mesmo realizando os passos sugeridos?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, http-status-404

Programo há 32 anos, mas iniciante em Java, portanto, quem votar negativo, gentileza comenta o motivo...
O que pode ser óbvio para você, pode ser inalcançável para outros.

Comecei um projeto Web com maven + JPA/Hibernate + JSF + primefaces.

- Ao abrir (tomcat) o arquivo index.xhtml (localhost:8080/new-hibernate-primefaces/index.xhtml), aparecem os labels criados, todos em uma única linha, fora de formatação..
- Nem mesmo um hello world funciona (hello.xhtml, quando chamo por hello.jsf)
- Ao abrir (tomcat) o arquivo index.JSF (localhost:8080/new-hibernate-primefaces/index.jsf), ocorre o erro abaixo:
  [image: Erro 404]

**TENTATIVAS:**

- Já tentei várias sugestões daqui (pt) e do stackoverflow.com, mas nenhuma das propostas funcionou.
  Também já marquei as opções em properties:
  "Botão direito no projeto", propriedades, Project Facets --> runtimes: marcar: Apache Tomcat v9.0 e DESMARCAR JRE.
- Já excluí e reconfigurei o Tomcat
- Marcar Dynamic Web Modulo 3.0
- Selecionar Java, JavaScript, JavaServer Faces 2.2, JPA
- Também já fiz um novo projeto do zero e o erro persiste.
- Um detalhe importante é que, na época, quando instalei o Eclipse, não havia marcado a opção "Desenvolvimento Web". Mas agora, adicionei os pacotes WebTools (acho que é isso).

-Localização dos arquivos:
/new-hibernate-primefaces/WebContent/index.xhtml
/new-hibernate-primefaces/WebContent/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml
/new-hibernate-primefaces/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml
/new-hibernate-primefaces/pom.xml
/new-hibernate-primefaces/src/main/java/META-INF/persistence.xml

**VERSÕES:**
Apache Tomcat: 9.0
Eclipse Version: 2020-09 (4.17.0)
JDK 11.0.8 (NÃO foi marcada no projeto, conforme recomendação do professor)

**Segue conteúdo dos principais arquivos:**

INDEX.XHTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"> 

<h:body>
    <h:form>
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">       
        <h:outputLabel for="ident" Value="Id" />
        <h:inputText id="ident" readonly="true" value="#{usuarioPessoaManagedBean.usuarioPessoa.id}" />

        <h:outputLabel for="nome" Value="Nome" />
        <h:inputText id="nome" value="#{usuarioPessoaManagedBean.usuarioPessoa.nome}" />

        <h:outputLabel for="sobrenome" Value="Sobrenome" />
        <h:inputText id="sobrenome" value="#{usuarioPessoaManagedBean.usuarioPessoa.sobrenome}" />

        <h:outputLabel for="email" Value="Email" />
        <h:inputText id="email" value="#{usuarioPessoaManagedBean.usuarioPessoa.email}" />

        <h:outputLabel for="login" Value="Login" />
        <h:inputText id="login" value="#{usuarioPessoaManagedBean.usuarioPessoa.login}" />

        <h:outputLabel for="senha" Value="Senha" />
        <h:inputSecret id="senha" value="#{usuarioPessoaManagedBean.usuarioPessoa.senha}" />

        <h:outputLabel for="idade" Value="Idade" />
        <h:inputText id="idade" value="#{usuarioPessoaManagedBean.usuarioPessoa.idade}" />
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
</h:body>

</html>
```

WEB.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>new-hibernate-primefaces</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
       <welcome-file>index.jsf</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<session-config>
<session-timeout>5</session-timeout>
</session-config>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>            
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>
</web-app>
```

FACES-CONFIG.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_3.xsd"
version="2.3">
</faces-config>
```

POM.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>new-hibernate-primefaces</groupId>
  <artifactId>new-hibernate-primefaces</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>new-hibernate-primefaces</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.faces/jsf-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.20</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.20</version> <!-- Corrigido -->
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.primefaces/primefaces -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>8.0</version>
    </dependency>
      
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.22</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.22.Final</version>
    </dependency>    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.22.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

**IMAGENS QUE PODEM SER ÚTEIS:**

[image: Java Build Path]

[image: Web Deployment Assembly]

[image: Project Facets #1]

[image: Project Facets #2]

[image: Project Facets #3]

[image: Java Server Faces - Library Configuration]

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Cara, tive um problema parecido com o seu utilizando essa versão do JSF. Quando voltei para a versão 2.2.9 ou 2.1.14 do JSF, rapidamente o problema foi solucionado. Mas olhando o seu código, percebi que as dependências do JSf api e impl estão com versões diferentes. Tente ajustar para versões idênticas.

```html
<dependency>
<groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
<artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
<version>2.2.20</version>
</dependency>
 
<!-- JSF -->
<dependency>
<groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
<artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
<version>2.2.20</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção, @Tguitarful Acho que, de tanto tentar, mexi nisso e não cuidei em corrigir, mas fiz isso e continua.

http://localhost:8888/new-hibernate-primefaces/index.jsf -> Erro 404
http://localhost:8888/new-hibernate-primefaces/index.xhtml -> Campos mal formatados

Comment: Cara, eu tbm não vi sucesso na versão 2.3 do JSF, de tanto tentar, desisti. Criei um padrão em utilizar a versão 4.0 do web e 2.2 do JSF e foi tranquilo. Vou aproveitar enquanto o Tomcat ainda possui suporte para ambos.